# Replace integers in a data frame column with other integers in R?

Tags: r, vector

I want to replace a vector in a dataframe that contains only 4 numbers to specific numbers as shown below

```
tt <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), each = 10)
df <- data.frame(tt)
```

I want to replace  `1 = 10; 2 = 200, 3 = 458, 4 = -0.1`

Comment: I'm curious: What output are you expecting from rep(c(rep(1,2,3,4), each = 10))?

Comment: OK...from there it easy!

Comment: `c(1,2,3,4)` will create a *numeric* (*float*) vector. To create *integer*: `c(1L,2L,3L,4L)`. Especially it will be obvious that `-0.1` is no *integer*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `recode` from `dplyr`. Note that the old values are written as character. And the new values are integers since the original column was integer:

```
library(tidyverse):
df %>% 
   mutate(tt = recode(tt, '1'= 10, '2' = 200, '3' = 458, '4' = -0.1))

     tt
1  10.0
2  10.0
3 200.0
4 200.0
5 458.0
6 458.0
7  -0.1
8  -0.1
```

Comment: While the index and arithmetic options are quite elegant for this case, THIS is the generally useful solution!

Answer (score 0):

To correct the error in the code in the question and provide for a shorter example we use the input in the Note at the end.  Here are several alternatives. `nos` defined in (1) is used in some of the others too. No packages are used.

**1) indexing** To get the result since the input is 1 to 4 we can use indexing.  This is probably the simplest solution given that the original values of tt are in 1:4.

```
nos <- c(10, 200, 458, -0.1)
transform(df, tt = nos[tt])
##      tt
## 1  10.0
## 2  10.0
## 3 200.0
## 4 200.0
## 5 458.0
## 6 458.0
## 7  -0.1
## 8  -0.1
```

**1a)** If the input is not necessarily in 1:4 then we could use this generalization

```
transform(df, tt = nos[match(tt, 1:4)])
```

**2) arithmetic** Another approach is to use arithmetic:

```
transform(df, tt = 10 * (tt == 1) + 
                   200 * (tt == 2) + 
                   458 * (tt == 3) +
                   -0.1 * (tt == 4))
```

**3) outer/matrix multiplication** This would also work:

```
transform(df, tt = c(outer(tt, 1:4, `==`) %*% nos))
```

**3a)** This is the same except we use model.matrix instead of outer.

```
transform(df, tt = c(model.matrix(~ factor(tt) + 0, df) %*% nos))
```

**4) factor**  The levels of the factor are 1:4 and the corresponding labels are defined by `nos`.  Extract the labels using format and then convert them to numeric.

```
transform(df, tt = as.numeric(format(factor(tt, levels = 1:4, labels = nos))))
```

**4a)** or as a pipeline

```
transform(df, tt = tt |> 
                     factor(levels = 1:4, labels = nos) |>
                     format() |>
                     as.numeric())
```

**5) loop** We can use a simple loop.  Nulling out i at the end is so that it is not made into a column.

```
within(df, { for(i in 1:4) tt[tt == i] <- nos[i]; i <- NULL })
```

**6) Reduce**  This is somewhat similar to (5) but implements the loop using Reduce.

```
fun <- function(tt, i) replace(tt, tt == i, nos[i])
transform(df, tt = Reduce(fun, init = tt, 1:4))
```

### Note

```
df <- data.frame(tt = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```